# What is cosmology/domain-wall correspondence?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, holographic-principle

Can someone give me an explanation for cosmology/domain-wall correspondence? I'm trying to understand holographic cosmology and this correspondence comes up a lot. It usually takes the form of relating a Loretnzian signature flat FLRW model with a scalar field to its Wick rotated Euclidean version. But why is

$ds^{2}=dt^2 +a(t)^2(dx^2...),$

the corresponding Euclidean signature domain-wall to the cosmological solution of

$ds^2=-dt^2+a(t)^2(dx^2....)$.

I hope the above clarifies what I'm asking for.

Thanks

Comment: My one and only bump.